# Cocos2d: how can I get a CCMenu item to call a selector once unselected?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccmenuitem

How can I get a CCMenu item to call a selector once unselected?

Is this even possible?

when adding a CCMenuItem I can specify as selector a function which will be called on button activation. What I would like is to be able to call a function once a button is not "selected" anymore (I mean selected and not activated).

I guess I have to override some methods but not sure which one :).

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass CCMenuItemWhatever and override one method (derived from CCMenuItem) :

```
-(void) unselected{
    [super unselected];
    [self myUnselectedExtension];
}

-(void) myUnselectedExtension{
    // whatever is your need , do it here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible without modifying CCMenu.

You can however run a scheduled update and check each `selected` property of the menu items, and observe any changes from the previous selected status (stored in an ivar for example).

Comment: I don't mind modifying a sublcass of CCMenu. But wasn't sure on where to start. I guess that I could have an extra method in the CCMenu subclass that makes and "boolean and" of all the selected properties and returns true or false. This combined with ur update suggestion should do. I'll try, so for now I upvote and then, once tried, I'll accept. Thanks :)